# Как на основе таблички сделать график в документе Word?

Tags: delphi, com, ms-word

Я создаю в Word небольшую табличку, а затем мне надо на её основе сделать график. Я нашел как добавить график, но код все время крашится с ошибкой в позиции

```
w := wrd.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddOLEObject('MSGraph.Chart.8');
```

и график создается, но создается не на основе данных в таблице. Как сделать правильно?

```
procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  wrd, w, Child: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
  StartRange: Variant;
begin
  wrd:=CoWordApplication.Create;
  wrd.Visible:=true;
  wrd.Documents.Add;
  wrd.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(wrd.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0), 5, 2);
  wrd.Visible := True;
  For i:=1 to 5 do
    begin
      wrd.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).Cell(i,1).Range.Text := i;
      wrd.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).Cell(i,2).Range.Text := i*i;
    end;
  w:=wrd.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddOLEObject('MSGraph.Chart.8');
  Child:=w.DiagramNode.Children.AddNode;
  for i:=1 to 5 do begin
    Child.Children.AddNode;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что ошибка возникает именно на указанной строке? У меня идет AV на следующей - `Child:=w.DiagramNode.Children.AddNode;`

Answer (score 2):

*Сейчас под рукой нет связки Delphi+Office, ответ даю по памяти и своим старым программам.*

Нет, ошибка у вас идёт в следующей строке, а не там, где вы предполагаете, поскольку код

```
  Child:=w.DiagramNode.Children.AddNode;
```

обращается к несуществующему объекту. Чтобы создать диаграмму из имеющихся табличных данных, нужно, фактически, выделить таблицу (очень помогает запись макросов с последующим анализом) и затем применить уже к выделению метод [InlineShapes.AddOLEObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes.addoleobject.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). Как-то так:

```
for i:=1 to 5 do
   begin
     wrd.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).Cell(i,1).Range.Text := i;
     wrd.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).Cell(i,2).Range.Text := i*i;
   end; // Тут кончается ваш код
wrd.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).Select;  // выбираем вашу таблицу  
wrd.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject('MSGraph.Chart.8','',FALSE,FALSE); // вставляем диаграмму по данным таблицы. 
// Я использую только первые 4 параметра, смотрите сами по ссылке выше, какие и сколько вам нужны
```

Данные вашей таблицы должны были быть скопированы в объект MS Graph. Дальше вы с ними можете работать. Например, так:

```
Doc:=wrd.ActiveDocument; // ну, мне так проще :)
Diag:=Doc.InlineShapes.Item(Doc.InlineShapes.Count); // ещё упрощаем доступ, вдруг понадобится доступ к объекту диаграммы в целом
Chart:= Diag.OLEFormat.Object; //а теперь только Chart, только хардкор :)
Chart.ChartType := 54; // ну, а дальше делаем, что хотим :)
Chart.Application.DataSheet.Activate;
Chart.Application.DataSheet.Cells.Clear;
Chart.ChartArea.Font.Bold := False;
Chart.Application.DataSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value :='11';
```

Разумеется, **Doc**, **Diag** и **Chart** - переменные типа `OleVariant`.

Comment: Работает :) Только почему MS Graph, а не MS Excel для диаграмм?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Не знаю, - это у автора спрашивайте :)